# How to pass all selected options to next selection on dynamic dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I am trying to create a dropdown list that dynamically populates from my database. There are 9 dropdown lists, and the 10th should automatically print the product number based on the above selections.

The code currently functions, but only partially. It will only use the data from the immediate previous selection to populate the next list; instead of referencing all previous selections. All the data is on a single table in the database.

This is causing options to display further down in the lists that should no longer be available given previous selections, and the product number in the 10th position is spitting out a huge amount of product numbers because it is only referencing the selection just above it.

I need each option select to be referenced by every select after it.

I've tried adding '".$_POST['']."' to my select statement, to my where clause to try to reference the previous selections, but it either returns nothing or results in an internal server error.

I'm not sure if this is the right track, or what is missing from my code to make this work.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Product Builder Tool</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

 $(".product_type").change(function()
         
 {
  var product_type=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'product_type='+ product_type;

  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".voltage").html(html);
    
   } 
  });
}); 
 
 $(".voltage").change(function()
 {
  var voltage=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'voltage='+ voltage;
 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".capacity").html(html);

   } 
  });
}); 
    
 $(".capacity").change(function()
 {
  var capacity=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'capacity='+ capacity;
    
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".modes").html(html);
   } 
  });
});  
 $(".modes").change(function()
 {
  var modes=$(this).val()
  var dataString = 'modes='+ modes;

 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".connection").html(html);
   } 
  });
}); 
 $(".connection").change(function()
 {
  var connection=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'connection='+ connection;
 
 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".status").html(html);
   } 
  });
});
  
 $(".status").change(function()
 {
  var status=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'status='+ status;
 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".enclosure").html(html);
   } 
  });
});
  
 $(".enclosure").change(function()
 {
  var enclosure=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'enclosure='+ enclosure;
 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".ul_type").html(html);
   } 
  });
});
  
 $(".ul_type").change(function()
 {
  var ul_type=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'ul_type='+ ul_type;
 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".options").html(html);
   } 
  });
});
  
 $(".options").change(function()
 {
  var options=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'options='+ options;
 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".product_number").html(html);
   } 
  });
});
  
 $(".product_number").change(function()
 {
  var product_number=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'product_number='+ product_number;
 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".price").html(html);
   } 
  });
});
  
 $(".price").change(function()
 {
  var price=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'price='+ price;
 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".picture_link").html(html);
   } 
  });
 });
});
 
</script>
<style>
label
{
font-weight:bold;
padding:10px;
}
div
{
 margin-top:100px;
}
select
{
 width:400px;
 height:35px;
 border:2px solid #456879;
 border-radius:10px;
}
 
.color {
 color:blue;
}
 
.link {
 color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
 
<body>
<h1 align="center" class="color">Product Builder Tool</h1>
<center>
<div>
<label>Product Type:</label> 
<select distinct name="product_type" class="product_type">
<option selected="selected">--Select Product Type--</option>
<?php
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT product_type FROM surge_unit");
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['product_type']; ?>"><?php echo $row['product_type']; ?></option>
        <?php
 } 
?>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Voltage and Phase:</label> <select name="voltage" class="voltage">
<option selected="selected">--Select Voltage and Phase--</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Capacity:</label> <select name="capacity" class="capacity">
<option selected="selected">--Select Capacity--</option>
</select>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Modes:</label> <select name="modes" class="modes">
<option selected="selected">--Select Modes Protected--</option>
</select>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Connection Type:</label> <select name="connection" class="connection">
<option selected="selected">--Select Connection Type--</option>
</select>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Status Indication:</label> <select name="status" class="status">
<option selected="selected">--Select Status Indication--</option>
</select>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Enclosure:</label> <select name="enclosure" class="enclosure">
<option selected="selected">--Select Enclosure--</option>
</select>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>UL 1449 Location Type:</label> <select name="ul_type" class="ul_type">
<option selected="selected">--Select UL 1449 Type--</option>
</select>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Options:</label> <select name="options" class="options">
<option selected="selected">--Select Options--</option>
</select>
<br>
<label>Product Number:</label>
<echo selected="selected" name="product_number" class="product_number">Product Number</echo>
<br><br><br>
</div>
<br />
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the get file for AJAX.

```js
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
if($_POST['product_type'])
{
 $voltage=$_POST['product_type'];
  
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT voltage FROM surge_unit WHERE product_type=:product_type");
 $stmt->execute(array('product_type' => $voltage));
 ?><option selected="selected">Select Voltage & Phase</option><?php
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row['voltage']; ?>"><?php echo $row['voltage']; ?></option>
        <?php
 }
}

if($_POST['voltage'])
{
 $capacity=$_POST['voltage'];
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT capacity
FROM surge_unit WHERE voltage =:voltage" );
 $stmt->execute(array('voltage' => $capacity));
 ?><option selected="selected">Select Capacity</option>
 <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['capacity']; ?>"><?php echo $row['capacity']; ?></option>
  <?php
 }
}

if($_POST['capacity'])
{
 $modes=$_POST['capacity'];
 
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT modes FROM surge_unit WHERE capacity=:capacity");
 $stmt->execute(array(':capacity' => $modes));
 ?><option selected="selected">Select Modes Protected</option>
 <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['modes']; ?>"><?php echo $row['modes']; ?></option>
  <?php
 }
}
if($_POST['modes'])
{
 $connection=$_POST['modes'];
 
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT connection FROM surge_unit WHERE modes=:modes");
 $stmt->execute(array(':modes' => $connection));
 ?><option selected="selected">Select Connection Type</option>
 <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['connection']; ?>"><?php echo $row['connection']; ?></option>
  <?php
 }
}
if($_POST['connection'])
{
 $status=$_POST['connection'];
 
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT status FROM surge_unit WHERE connection=:connection");
 $stmt->execute(array(':connection' => $status));
 ?><option selected="selected">Select Status Indication</option>
 <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['status']; ?>"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></option>
  <?php
 }
}
if($_POST['status'])
{
 $enclosure=$_POST['status'];
 
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT enclosure FROM surge_unit WHERE status=:status");
 $stmt->execute(array(':status' => $enclosure));
 ?><option selected="selected">Select Enclosure</option>
 <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['enclosure']; ?>"><?php echo $row['enclosure']; ?></option>
  <?php
 }
}
if($_POST['enclosure'])
{
 $ul_type=$_POST['enclosure'];
 
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT ul_type FROM surge_unit WHERE enclosure=:enclosure");
 $stmt->execute(array(':enclosure' => $ul_type));
 ?><option selected="selected">Select UL 1449 Type</option>
 <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['ul_type']; ?>"><?php echo $row['ul_type']; ?></option>
  <?php
 }
}
if($_POST['ul_type'])
{
 $options=$_POST['ul_type'];
 
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT options FROM surge_unit WHERE ul_type=:ul_type");
 $stmt->execute(array(':ul_type' => $options));
 ?><option selected="selected">Select Options</option>
 <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['options']; ?>"><?php echo $row['options']; ?></option>
  <?php
 }
}
if($_POST['options'])
{
 $product_number=$_POST['options'];
 
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT product_number FROM surge_unit WHERE options=:options");
 $stmt->execute(array(':options' => $product_number));
 ?>
 <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
  <?php echo $row['product_number']; ?><?php $row['SELECT product_number FROM surge_unit WHERE options=id9']; ?>
  <?php
 }
}
?>
```

What am I missing to make this work properly?
I'm pretty sure my select statements need to have a bunch of AND clauses in the WHERE clause, but I can't get it to function at all when I try. Is Ajax not sending the proper information in order for it to pick up earlier selections?

Comment: Start with some basic troubleshooting with your browser's network inspector. Do the requests get sent? Do the POST parameters look reasonable? Is there a response? Do the contents of the response look reasonable?

Comment: Also, there is a maxim in programming called DRY, or Don't Repeat Yourself. You have taken this maxim, run it over with a truck, backed up, and run it over again. :)

Comment: This is what I tried. ("SELECT DISTINCT capacity
FROM surge_unit WHERE voltage =:voltage AND product_type=.'".$POST['product_type']."'" );
 $stmt->execute(array('voltage' => $capacity));  It gives me 500 (internal server error)

Comment: Scratch that, no internal error(there was a syntax problem), but it still doesn't return a result for the next list. It's not throwing any errors at all, it just isn't returning data for the next list.